# Is it possible to retrieve logs from kubernetes pods through API endpoint from AWS EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, grafana-loki

I have a kubernetes running on EKS AWS. I want to know it if its possible to access the pods logs through the API endpoint AWS offers for the cluster.

I want to send the logs to a serverless loki running in a different service. I'm not allowed to install nor loki neither promtail inside the kubernetes for company reasons, that's why I want to access the logs through the API endpoint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger Kubernetes/EKS cron job via HTTP call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239327/trigger-kubernetes-eks-cron-job-via-http-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete [guide](https://nieldw.medium.com/curling-the-kubernetes-api-server-d7675cfc398c) how to do that using a service account token. To follow the log append `?follow=true` like:

```
curl -s $APISERVER/api/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/pods/<pod name>/log?follow=true --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
--cacert ca.crt
```